# When is $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$ a Dedekind domain for an algebraic number $\theta$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

The title says all. Suppose that $f\in \mathbb{Z}[t]$ is an irreducible polynomial (over $\mathbb{Q}$) and $\theta$ is a root of $f$.

1. Can we determine when is $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$ is a Dedekind domain?
2. As a special case, is it true that $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]$ is a Dedekind domain if $f$ is monic and $\theta$ is a root of $f$?

Comment: is $\Bbb Z[\sqrt5]$ a Dedekind domain? (I don't know, but it's not a ring of integers, so it might not be.)

Comment: @GregMartin A Dedekind domain should be integrally closed. But the integral closure of $\Bbb{Z} [ \theta ]$ is a ring of integers.

Comment: [Relevant discussion on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21267/which-number-fields-are-monogenic-and-related-questions)